# gwt-maven-plugin: Only generate necessary js files

Tags: java, javascript, maven, gwt

I'm using the gwt-maven-plugin to compile a module using maven.  The problem is that there are a lot of generated .js files that I believe to be unused (e.g. uploadDialog, map, filetree) in the target folder.  Is there a way to set the plugin to only include javascript files used by the application or is the best solution to remove the javascript files manually after the build.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The GWT compiler is already smart enough to only generate the code that some application path will use. If there are "unnecessary files" then there is unnecessary code in your application.

Comment: Would you say this applies to extensions to gwt such as Ext (the free, non sencha one).  I think it may be the culprit, but having trouble finding the javav class to javascript file mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT Ext (not-Sencha) and SmartGWT, to name a few, are both wrappers around JS libs, and the GWT compiler won't pick the bits from the external JS lib that you happen to use. If you want to optimize this, then it's up to you.

Comment: Sorry, you've got us backward there - Sencha GXT used to be called *Ext GWT* (the official change happened for version 3), and under either name is all Java. You are thinking of *GWT Ext*, which was a wrapper around Ext JS 2.

Comment: Answer edited. I couldn't remember the proper name, and thought GXT would the shortcut for Gwt-eXT, so the other would then be Ext GWT ;-)

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to look at all the classes I'm using in the source and make sure there's nothing laying around I'm not using anymore, so its not pulling in that javascript code.  Thanks